# Modify variable in expression tree to check recursion depth

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, odata, ef-core-5.0

To query our data from the frontend we use an OData .NET 5 API. To map our database objects to DTOs we use some custom mapper methods. An earlier problem we solved requires us to decompile the lambda to an expression tree as can be seen in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66258628/11440459).

The problem we now have has to do with a cirulair reference as can be seen in the snippet below:

```
[Computed]
public static AuthorDTO ToDto(this Author author, int depth)
{
    return depth < 0 ? null : new AuthorDTO
    {
        Firstname = author.Firstname,
        Lastname = author.Lastname,
        Id = author.Id,
        Books = author.Books.Select(book => book.ToDto(depth - 1)) // This line causes the problem
    };
}

[Computed]
public static BookDTO ToDto(this Book book, int depth)
{
    return depth < 0 ? null : new BookDTO
    {
        AuthorId = book.AuthorId,
        Author = book.Author.ToDto(depth - 1), // This line causes the problem
        Id = book.Id,
        ISBN = book.ISBN,
        Title = book.Title
    };
}
```

This gets called as follows in our controller:

```
// Get data
IQueryable<Author> authors = dbContext.Set<Author>().Include(a => a.Books);

// Convert to DTO
IQueryable<AuthorDTO> result = CustomMapper.ProjectTo(authors, 2);

return Ok(result.DecompileAsync());
```

We understand that when the function gets decompiled by DelegateDecompiler the value of 'depth' will never be decreased. This causes an infinite loop and raises a stackoverflow exception.

I created an extremely simplified minimal version of our problem [in this repo](https://github.com/NielsDWG/TheBookStoreTestProject). What should we try next? We hope someone can send us in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will not work. DelegateDecompiler will iterate to stack overflow because it does not evaluate expressions (depth in your case) but just inject lambda.

Comment: Is there no other solution? Is there something we can try?